# Duplicating the "type" of user for template projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I'm working on building templates for `projects` and part of that involves adding template `team_members` to the `project`, where `team_members` acts as a join table between `projects` and `users`.

For instance, I know that my `project` template will have `team_members` of type "Developer" and "Manager", but I don't know which `users` will fill those roles at the template level.

If I were to map it out with some JSON data, this is what it looks like conceptually:

```
team_member_types: [
  { id: 1, name: "Developer" },
  { id: 2, name: "Manager" },
],

project: { id: 1, title: "Template project title", template: true },

team_members: [
  { project_id: 1, team_member_type_id: 1, user_id: nil }, # => "Developer"
  { project_id: 1, team_member_type_id: 2, user_id: nil }, # => "Manager"
]
```

When I use the template to make a real project, I want to add real users as the `team_members`, but I want to filter the list of `users` based on what role I'm adding them on.

For instance, when I want to add the real `user` for the "Developer" role, I only want to see a list of users who are marked as "Developers".  That means I have a `team_member_type` association on the `users` table as well.

```
user: { id: 1, name: "John Smith", team_member_type: "Developer" }
```

And when I'm on my form adding in the real `user`:

```
@team_member_type = TeamMemberType.find_by(name: "Developer")
@filtered_users = User.where(team_member_type_id: @team_member_type)
```

The issue I'm running into, is that it seems the `team_member` join table has to have a `team_member_type` associated on it to mark it during the template phase, but the associated `user` also has a `team_member_type` associated to it in order to filter.  So when I add a real `user` to the `project` this is the result:

```
@team_member = TeamMember.find(1)
@team_member.team_member_type.name = "Developer"
@team_member.user.team_member_type.name = "Developer"
```

I have the same "data" being stored in 2 different ways.  This seems like a problem, but I'm not sure how I can address it with my current DB structure.  Is there a way to re-organize the associations so I only have this data stored once?

The actual Rails models look like this:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_members
end

class TeamMember < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project 
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team_member_type
end

class TeamMemberType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_members
  has_many :users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_members
  belongs_to :team_member_type
end
```